# [iPhone]A zone which user can't interact, why?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, touch, fullscreen

Plese refer to below image to get detail of my problem:

[image]

This maybe relate to Status bar???

*Note: this is a full-screen application. My way to do this:
1. add "Status bar is initially hidden" information property to  xxx-Info.plist.
2. In all screen of app: set "Status Bar" to none.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely loading a nib with your control set to 320x460, instead of 320x480.  Post how you are generating this view and we can help more.

Comment: I second that. Setting the Status Bar to none doesn't resize the view to 320X480. It still remains 320X460 and you need to change it manually.

Comment: I'm set size is 480x320 (rotate to landscape). This is my simply sample code, please refer: http://cid-f2619b9ec41167b6.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Public/TapScreen.zip

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening on the device or just in the simulator?

The simulator has/had bugs that stop it reporting touches in the status bar area.

Comment: This is happening on the simulator. I will test in device and report here.

Comment: Yes, this is a known glitch with the iPhone Simulator relating to landscape mode applications.  I've seen the same thing in my application.  It should go away on the actual device.

Answer (score 0):

It really does look that your view is not big enough, and is sized to a screen with the status bar.

How do you create the UIControl? Using a NIB? What's the frame you assign to it? Post some code.

Comment: I'm using NIB file and frame of it: width = 480, height = 320.    
This is my simply Sample code, please refer to it:    

http://cid-f2619b9ec41167b6.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Public/TapScreen.zip